# NodeJS SerialPort not connecting?

Tags: node.js

Hello hope someone can help me with this problem i am trying to retrieve the scale data to the console for now but when I do so it seems its not connecting with the correct parameters for example

```
const { SerialPort, ReadlineParser } = require('serialport')
const { io } = require('socket.io')(3000);

// list serial ports:
// SerialPort.list().then (
//     ports => ports.forEach(port =>console.log(port.manufacturer + ' ' + port.path)),
//     err => console.log(err)
// )

const serialport = new SerialPort({ 
    path: 'COM3',
    baudRate: 9600,
    dataBits: 7,
    parity: 'even',
    stopBits: 1,
    flowControl: false
});

const parser = new ReadlineParser()
serialport.pipe(parser)

serialport.on('open', showPortOpen);
parser.on('data', readSerialData);
serialport.on('close', showPortClose);
serialport.on('error', showError);

function showPortOpen() {
  console.log('port open. Port: ' + serialport.path + ', Data rate: ' + serialport.baudRate + ', Data bits: ' + serialport.dataBits + ', parity: ' + serialport.parity);
}

function readSerialData(data) {
  console.log(data);
  return;
}

function showPortClose() {
  console.log('port closed.');
}

function showError(error) {
  console.log('Serial port error: ' + error);
}
```

i get the following console log when its ran

```
port open. Port: COM3, Data rate: 9600, Data bits: undefined, parity: undefined
```

why is it not connecting with the databits, parity, stopbits

Comment: Perhaps windows dosnt support that. 7 Databits is strange. What displays `console.log(serialport.port)`? What kind of serial device are you trying to communicate with?

Comment: ```WindowsPortBinding {
  fd: 564,
  openOptions: {
    dataBits: 7,
    lock: true,
    stopBits: 1,
    parity: 'even',
    rtscts: false,
    rtsMode: 'handshake',
    xon: false,
    xoff: false,
    xany: false,
    hupcl: true,
    path: 'COM3',
    baudRate: 9600,
    flowControl: false
  },
  writeOperation: null
}
```
its an mettler toledo scale using for shipping

Comment: Looks good for me. Have you tried to read/write something? I dont see a problem here.

Comment: yeah i am trying to read it and nothing is being displayed its like its not even running the function readSerialData

Comment: What device are you trying to communicate with? I hate it to repeat my questions...

Comment: its a mettler toledo scale using for weighting

Comment: Model Number?  Does it even end the transmission with a newline? If so, what kind of sequence? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation 
What do you see if you pipe serialport to stdout (without a parser)?

Comment: the model is BC-60 you have to send W to retrieve a weight i used putty to test that out so i guess i need to find a way to send W and then read it.

Comment: Is this all code? Wait for the serialport to open, and then just do a `serialport.write("W")`. Then you should receive something.